# Achieve true determinism in CPLEX

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex

I'm unable to achieve true determinism in CPLEX (I'm using the DOCplex python API).
Even if the best integer optimal solution is found without going to timeout (so it is expected to be unique), two identical separate runs leads to different results.

I'm setting the model parameters in this way:

```
cplex_model.parameters.randomseed = 42
cplex_model.parameters.threads = 1
```

Also I'm fixing every random seed that could be involved:

```
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
```

Comment: It looks like either a bug in Cplex, or some other hidden non-deterministic behavior in Python

Comment: same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71188150/achieve-true-determinism-in-cplex